# Replit Node Version

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to change replit's node version to 16? I updated my whole bot code on VSC but now I have nowhere to host it, and I don't have any money to buy a hosting service.

If anyone has a way to change the node version, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search confirms that Repl.it does not provide facilities to explicitly set the Node.js version for your runtime.

> You cannot modify a language's version on repl.it if it does not have a separate language for the version (e.g. Python 3&2).

[<sup>source</sup>](https://replit.com/talk/ask/change-node-version/You-cannot-modify-a-languages-version-o/16181)